# Carry-on policy for travel humidifiers - United Airlines

Tags: hand-luggage, united-airlines, tsa, prohibited-items

I am traveling to a state with dry air, and I was thinking of taking a travel humidifier with me. Can I carry something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NAAH6EL) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JL4LZ4) or [this](https://www.cvs.com/shop/vicks-warm-steam-vaporizer-v150sg-prodid-856939?skuid=856939) in my carry-on on a United Airlines flight?

I understand personal humidifiers are not allowed, I am asking about one which I can keep in my carry-on case.

I called my hotel and asked if they provide a humidifier for the room upon request, and they do not.

Answer (score 2):

With very few exceptions, the airlines do not care what you bring on the plane - as long as it fits within your carry-on allowance, and has made it past TSA, then the airlines will generally be fine with it.

The TSA "[What Can I Bring?](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring)" website doesn't have anything for "humidifier", and whilst that doesn't give a definitive answer I'd say the chances of it not being allowed are zero - as long as there is no liquid in it at the time that you're trying to take it through security.

Technically as it's an electronic device larger than a cell phone you will need to remove it from your bag as you go through security - although as the electronics part is small you probably won't have an issue even if you don't.

Note that this is just discussing taking it on the plane - if your plan is to actually use it in flight that's a completely different story and would NOT be allowed by the airline.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reason why not, so long as you empty all the water out of it.  People bring miscellaneous electrical appliances on airplanes all the time, and I don't see anything special about these.

If you want to make sure, you can [ask TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all).